# How to install libfdk_aac for FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, centos6

While compiling `ffmpeg` it's showing Unknown encoder `libfdk_aac` error.
Can anyone explain how I can install `libfdk_aac` for my FFMPEG?

I am using `centos 6`.

Comment: More info. don't throw together stange formatting. Don't use "thank you" phrases, they are discouraged on StackOverflow, because they just bloat your question.

Comment: i am using this command..../usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i ffmpeg/test1.flv  ffmpeg/test1.mp4

Comment: I reverted the changes or rithiin, which only made it harder to read the question. People, when you edit a question, please do make sure it's **good** for the question.

Answer (score 4):

libfdk_aac is considered non-free and therefore non-redistributable, so you should find no builds with support for this encoder. Therefore, you must compile.

The FFmpeg Wiki has a compile guide with step-by-step instructions for CentOS. The resulting `ffmpeg` binary will support libfdk_aac:

[FFmpeg Wiki: Compile FFmpeg on CentOS](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Centos)

Note that this guide performs a "local installation" into the `~/bin` directory of the user following the guide: this is to avoid conflicts with the package management system, system files, and repository packages. Also, it allows a non-superuser to compile, such as on a shared server (assuming the build dependencies, like `make`, are available). This works fine for most users, but depending on your needs you may have to move the binary somewhere else in your `PATH` environment variable.

Alternatively, you could just use [a different AAC encoder](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AAC). Feed it enough bits and you'll do fine.

---

<sub>Generally, "link-only" answers are discouraged, but I'm going to make an exception in this case. I am hesitant to copy and paste the content from the link because of the size of the guide and the likely chance that the answer will become outdated as the guide is updated (such as what happens to the many rotting copycat compile guides).</sub>